# How to load a Range in Excel into MSSQL using VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to load a data range from Excel into a DB.

The code that I have is the following:

```
Sub InsertARange()

    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim stCon As String, stSQL As String
    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    stCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Initial Catalog=SSCReporting;Data Source=cra-uk-infra-sql;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=xxx;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
    cnt.ConnectionString = stCon
    stSQL = "INSERT INTO _sqlTest select * from [MacroSQL$A1:D10]"

    cnt.Open
    rst.Open stSQL, cnt, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
    Set cnt = Nothing
End Sub
```

With this code I get an error message "Invalid object name MacroSQL$A1:D10"

I tried also selecting the tab name in the stSQL string as

```
stSQL = "INSERT INTO _sqlTest select * from [DB_RangeUpload$]
```

I was using the code samples that appear [here](https://support.microsoft.com/af-za/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w), but maybe this is only for select queries and does not work with insert queries.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to load Excel data into a SQL Server database, but this method is so very far from something that might work, that it's not even worth trying to fix it.  You are basically expecting Excel to find data in a range, then... well what exactly?  Are you expecting it to guess which table you want it to put in, what goes where, which columns to use, etc.?  The simplest method is to use dynamic SQL, but this sort of thing is much easier outside VBA, either in a .NET application, or using VSTO, or SSIS, or even from SQL Server using Excel as a data source (for example).

Comment: Richard, thanks for your reply. I have defined what table to load it in: _sqlTest. This same code is working loading single values (stSQL = "INSERT INTO _sqlTest (Reference, Amount) values ('a', 123)). What I don't know is how to load a range.

Comment: I think that you'll need to build the `insert into` statement by looping the range.  In your tests, `(Reference, Amount) ` are these the only fields, as your range is 4 columns.  I believe it would be best to also use `.execute` your sql on the connection.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I'll try to use a look. I thought it would be an alternative to a line by line upload.